# How to run a Protractor test after click and content load finished?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I have this test code:

```
element(by.cssContainingText('a[ng-click="select()"]', 'Visual')).click()
browser.sleep(1000)
expect(element.all(by.tagName('angular-chart')).count()).toEqual(1);
```

But it hangs until timeout reach and then shows:

> Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by `jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL`.

I suppose I need to wait for the content to load somehow then run the test?

If I replace the expect construct with the one below, it passes:

```
expect(true).toEqual(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
element(by.cssContainingText('a[ng-click="select()"]', 'Visual')).click().then( function(){
      expect(element.all(by.tagName('angular-chart')).count()).toEqual(1);
});
```

Most calls in protractor returns a promise. 
http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.click

Comment: I tried this and other variants but they didn't help. Seems like there is some wrong logic in the template partial I use which prevents the code from running properly.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try adding an explicit wait to wait for the `angular-chart` element [to become present](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.presenceOf):

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

element(by.cssContainingText('a[ng-click="select()"]', 'Visual')).click()

var chart = element(by.tagName('angular-chart'));
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(chart), 10000);
```

You might also look into increasing [jasmine timeout intervals](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md).